# why does my Java session values refuses to update?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, session, servlets

I have a strange problem here and I dont know if any one has an idea what could cause it. I'm working on a Java EE (Servlets & JSPs) web application project that uses AJAX to update the web page. When I test it on my localhost server (im using Tomcat 7.0.26) it works perfectly well. But when I run the same application on my hosting server, some of the values or the page itself refuse to update correctly. These values are stored in a session attribute and when they are typed in they are sent to the servlet via AJAX request, like I said, they work well as expected on my localhost but on the hosting server that I subscribed, there are errors. Does anyone have any idea what is going on there please? The site is http://www.optdesolver.com

Comment: it seems to work good for me...

Comment: You should post the errors and code

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: Yes initially it works fine, but when you change the number of Decision Variables, the number of text fields generated should correspond to the number of Decision Variables and it does not. Please check it again. Also observe the minimize/maximize switch does not update correctly as well.

Comment: @Hardik Mishra: The page does not display errors, but it is not working correctly. As for the source code, I dont know which one to post since I have too many Servlets, JSPs, JavaScripts, and HTML files. I dont know which one will help.

Comment: works fine with me too. The number of text fields generated is correct when I click **Enter**.

Comment: First thing, You mentioned in the post "there are errors" and second you may post the code excerpt where you set values in the session and access session in the application

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a number of things

1. Your server configuration. How long that the session timeout is set?
2. Your app has a cache of files.
3. Your browser has some cache of files.
4. You are not deploying your proyect properly.
5. You have multple instances in your server.
6. You have to restart the server in order to make it refresh its contents.

I suggest you use some kind of version number in your html to verify that is not a cache realated problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The session timeout as configured in my deployment descriptor is 3000 minutes,  what is this cache of files?, how is it possible for me to run multiple instances of the same application on my server?, My server must always be restarted after deploying, how do I use this "version number"?